# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ubuntu-14.04

This is a comment Problem with ionic in ubuntu,The solution is to add the Android home to the path 
But my problem is that Even the ANDROID_HOME is already in the PATH and When i Type

```
 $ Android
```

In The terminal its open Android SDK

### Why ionic Can not find The android Home?!!

Update 
After adding android home to the path in this terminal session

The output of echo $ANDROID_HOME is the path to android Sdk 
But Still accrue the same error?!

Comment: What happens if you write `echo $ANDROID_HOME` in a terminal?

Comment: Nothing its Empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 days of searching And Tried so many methods to fix this problem 
I fix it with theses  instructions

1. Install node with nvm
2. Never user root to install node or npm

Now its works fine for my and ionic ca see Android SDK home

Answer (score 3):

Your global PATH relies in /etc/environment so if you edit it here it should be also available in ionic.

After you edit it you can reloaded by executing:

```
source /etc/environment
```

If you are creating a ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile in your user's home dir that will only be loaded in a shell environment.

Make sure that your /etc/environment file looks something like this:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/eics/Android/Sdk
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi‌​n:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools”
```

Comment: Even the output of Echo $ANROID_HOME is The android SDK path

Comment: Ionic project can not find it

Comment: What does 'cat /etc/environment' output? If you are using a shell terminal end run echo $ANDROID_HOME it will output it because your .profile or .bash_profile was loaded for your user. But it's not available in your entire environment. Use /etc/environment.

Comment: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
ANDROID_HOME=/home/eics/Android/Sdk

Comment: The problem is that you have not modified your PATH variable. Try editing your /etc/environment like this: ANDROID_HOME=/home/eics/Android/Sdk
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi‌​n:/bin:/usr/games:/u‌​sr/local/games:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools”

Comment: So ,How i can do that ?!

Comment: Make sure that you have rights to edit /etc/environment and use a shell editor like vi or nano and make sure to run: 'source /etc/environment' in order to reload the changes.

Comment: After that The output of $ANDROID_HOME still empty

Comment: the output of cat etc/environment is ANDROID_HOME=/home/eics/Android/Sdk PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi‌​‌​n:/bin:/usr/games:‌​/u‌​sr/local/games:$‌​ANDROID_HOME/tools:$‌​ANDROID_HOME/platfor‌​m-tools

Comment: The etc/environment file is the same as you said ,But echo $ANDROID_HOME is still empty

Answer (score 2):

The error is very clear and as you wrote in the comments

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

yields an empty result.

In Ubuntu, to set an environment variable globally you edit `/etc/environment` and there you would add

```
ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk
```

Where you actually provide a real path, after you have done that you might need to do `source /etc/environment` to make it work in your current session.

If you only want to do it for your terminal, you can edit `~/.bashrc` instead and add

```
export $ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk
```

Comment: The output of echo $ANDROID_HOME is the path to android Sdk But Still accrue the same error?!

Comment: eics@eics-Vostro-1540:~/demoapp$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/eics/Android/Sdk
eics@eics-Vostro-1540:~/demoapp$ sudo ionic build android

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

Running command: /home/eics/demoapp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/eics/demoapp


add to body class: platform-android

Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Comment: Try add it to the global path in `/etc/environment` too

Answer (score 0):

export/set $Android to ANDROID_HOME to your environment variables